# CRUD genérico ou SQLs especificas

Tags: banco-de-dados

Em um sistema que tende a crescer em número de classes e de usuários, qual seria a melhor abordagem para se trabalhar com acesso ao banco de dados?

1. criar um CRUD genérico? ou
2. criar métodos específicos para inserir e atualizar cada classe model que está persistida no Banco de dados?

A meu ver a 1ª abordagem tem a vantagem de se escrever somente uma vez o código pra inserir e remover e outros, porém tem a desvantagem de não se saber previamente as SQLs disponíveis e de não prover queries complexas. A 2º abordagem tem como vantagem a simplicidade, a capacidade de ser específica, e como desvantagem ter de reescrever o código das consultas simples.

Qual seria a melhor abordagem para a situação apontada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A melhor abordagem depende sempre do objetivo colocado no horizonte.

O modelo de desenvolvimento baseado na criação de CRUDs sempre vai levar vantagem na rapidez do desenvolvimento, considerando que muitas coisas são feitas em automático. A abordagem vale a pena porque não é todo sistema que é inteiramente complexo. Na maior parte dos casos, [os sistemas seguem o bom e velho Princípio de Pareto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_de_Pareto), em que *80% dos gargalos de desempenho estão concentrados em até 20% do código*. Nestes casos, não há grandes ganhos quando a produção de código é artesanal, ou seja, feita sentença a sentença.

Mesmo quando o sistema tem uma tendência de desenvolvimento contínuo, a segunda abordagem é mais interessante no momento em que problemas de desempenho são sentidos. É aquele momento no ciclo de vida do código em que telas e ações que antes eram rápidas começam a se tornar lentas. Aí vale a pena estudar o plano de execução das sentenças, reescrever o código buscando otimização, e assim por diante.

Ainda assim, no atual estágio dos frameworks baseados em mapeamento objeto-relacional (os famosos ORM's), a ideia é justamente que o próprio framework faça um trabalho de otimização prévio, livrando a equipe de desenvolvimento a gastar tempo com otimização num estágio inicial de desenvolvimento.

Comment: então a segunda solução (mais simples, porem mais demorada) seria a mais adequada por ser mais legível e eficiente (em desempenho).

Comment: Num segundo momento de desenvolvimento, conforme o sistema ganha complexidade, sim, mas não tem porquê ter isso no início do desenvolvimento.